# Splitting and Concating a JS array into chunks by counting the length of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, split, reduce

Let say I have an array as following:

```
let inputArr = [
"Name: Jarina Begum↵Age: 70 years↵↵",
"Tab. Mycofree (250 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১/২ টা -- ১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
"Cap. Losectil (20 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার আগে↵",
"Tab. Rupin (10 mg)↵0 + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
"Savoy Sulphur Soap↵.১.৫ মাস -- নিয়মিত ব্যবহার করবেন।↵",
"Advices:",
"১।নিয়মিত ওষুধ সেবন করবেন।, ",
"২।সাধারন সাবান লাগাবেন না।, ",
"৩।পরিধেয় জামা কাপড় Savlon/Detol দিয়ে ধুয়ে ফেলবেন, ",
"৪।পরিবারের সবার চিকিৎসা করতে হবে।, ",
"৫।কবিরাজী ও হোমিওপাথি করবেন না, ",
"৬।ডাক্তার এর পরামর্শ বাতিত ওষুধ বন্ধ করবেন না।"
];
```

I want to make a new array from the array above, where the character size of every element should be **<=300**.

So, I've to concatenate the elements one after another, count the `character size` & `index` of the array, while the size of concatenate string cross the limit [let say in this case, 300]; then push it into a new array, and start counting the character from next index as considering the size of character from 0.

The loop will continue until the last index of `inputArr`.

I've also made sure if the size of any element is **>300** then I've to break that element with the limit of 300.

The expected output will be like below:

```
[
"Name: Jarina Begum↵Age: 70 years↵↵Tab. Mycofree (250 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১/২ টা -- ১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵Cap. Losectil (20 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার আগে↵Tab. Rupin (10 mg)↵0 + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵Savoy Sulphur Soap↵.১.৫ মাস -- নিয়মিত ব্যবহার করবেন।↵Advices:",
"১।নিয়মিত ওষুধ সেবন করবেন।, ২।সাধারন সাবান লাগাবেন না।, ৩।পরিধেয় জামা কাপড় Savlon/Detol দিয়ে ধুয়ে ফেলবেন, ৪।পরিবারের সবার চিকিৎসা করতে হবে।, ৫।কবিরাজী ও হোমিওপাথি করবেন না, ৬।ডাক্তার এর পরামর্শ বাতিত ওষুধ বন্ধ করবেন না।"
];
```

So, once again, the requirements are in shorts:

1. Create a new array from a given array, by concatenating the elements and the character size of the elements of new array should be **<=300**
2. If the character size of any element of the given array is **>300** break it with the limit of 300 and splice into the given array, and continuing the requirements one.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using `reduce()` @DirkR

Comment: You can use `.match` like the solution I posted....does that help?

Comment: No, This is not the expected result. I do not want to count only the characters.
The element of the array has broken in the middle of the line!

It should not be. If the concatenation of the next element cross 300 characters, then it stops at the last one. @AbhisarTripathi

Comment: You need to track two indexes: one for previous whitespace character and another one for current whitespace character. If your index for current whitespace character is greater than 300 - you need to slice from beginning to previous whitespace character. But, if your index for current whitespace character is not greater than 300, you just update the previous index with your current and continue the loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is an array, not a string, and I want to concatenate the next index to the previous index if the length of concatenated string <=300 @EugeneObrezkov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks to everyone who spends time to solve my problem, though that didn't fulfill my requirements. Anyways, finally, I've solved it using the traditional loop.

I've written three functions to solve this problem, one function is for the first requirement, and the other two for the second requirement.

**Function One:** Where I pass two parameters, one is for the array and another one is the length of the character limit.

Inside the first function I've called the second function, pass there the given array, and store the result as input array.

```
const chunkSmsArr = (arr, len=300) => {
    let inputArr = checkElLength(arr, len);
    let outputArr = [],
        msgString = '',
            count = 0;

    for(let i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        if( (msgString+inputArr[i]).length <= len ) {
            msgString += inputArr[i];
        } else {
            msgString = '';
            msgString += inputArr[i];
            count++;
        }
        outputArr[count] = msgString;
    }

    return outputArr;
}
```

**Function Two:** This function checks every element of the given array, if found the length of any element **>300**, then it called the third function, break the string into array and splice it at the position of current iteration.

```
const checkElLength = (inputArr, len) => {
    let outputArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (inputArr[i].length > len) {
            let breakedSmsArr = breakSmsArrString(inputArr[i], len);
            inputArr.splice(i, 1, ...breakedSmsArr);
        }
    }
    outputArr = inputArr;
    return outputArr;
}
```

**Function Three:** Where I also pass two parameters, one is the string which I need to break into array elements, and another one is the length of the character limit.

```
const breakSmsArrString = (str, len) => {
    let curr = len, prev = 0;
    let output = [];

    while(str[curr]) {
        if(str[curr++] == ' ') {
            output.push(str.substring(prev,curr));
            prev = curr;
            curr += len;
        } else {
            let currReverse = curr;
            do {
                if(str.substring(currReverse - 1, currReverse) == ' ') {
                    output.push(str.substring(prev,currReverse));
                    prev = currReverse;
                    curr = currReverse + len;
                    break;
                }
                currReverse--;
            } while(currReverse > prev)
        }
    }
    output.push(str.substr(prev)); 
    return output;
}
```

So, now you can make a try with `console.log` to see the output:

```
console.log(chunkArr(inputArr, 300));
```

Comment: My one is also working :) but you checked when it had typo

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Yes, after you edit the answer, now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a optimal way using `.match` and `RegEx` something like this -:

```
let charLimitArray = inputArr.join().match(/.{1,300}/g)
console.log(charLimitArray);
```

```js
let inputArr = [
"Name: Jarina Begum↵Age: 70 years   ↵↵",
"Tab. Mycofree (250 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১/২ টা -- ১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
"Cap. Losectil (20 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার আগে↵",
"Tab. Rupin (10 mg)↵0 + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
"Savoy Sulphur Soap↵.১.৫ মাস -- নিয়েমিত ব্যবহার করবেন।↵",
"Advices:",
"১।নিয়মিত ওষুধ সেবন করবেন।, ",
"২।সাধারন সাবান লাগাবেন না।, ",
"৩।পরিধেয় জামা কাপড় Savlon/Detol দিয়ে ধুয়ে ফেলবেন, ",
"৪। পরিবারের সবার চিকিৎসা করতে হবে।, ",
"৫।কবিরাজী ও হমিওপাথি করবেন না, ",
"৬।ডাক্তার এর পরামর্শ বাতিত অষুধ বন্দ করবেন না।"
];
console.log(inputArr.join().match(/.{1,300}/g))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: No, This is not the expected result. I do not want to count only the characters.
The element of the array has broken in the middle of the line!

It should not be. If the concatenation of the next element cross 300 characters, then it stops at the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with a simple `for` loop.

```js
  let inputArr = [
  "Name: Jarina Begum↵Age: 70 years   ↵↵",
  "Tab. Mycofree (250 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১/২ টা -- ১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
  "Cap. Losectil (20 mg)↵১ + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার আগে↵",
  "Tab. Rupin (10 mg)↵0 + 0 + ১ টা -- .১.৫ মাস -- খাওয়ার পরে↵",
  "Savoy Sulphur Soap↵.১.৫ মাস -- নিয়েমিত ব্যবহার করবেন।↵",
  "Advices:",
  "১।নিয়মিত ওষুধ সেবন করবেন।, ",
  "২।সাধারন সাবান লাগাবেন না।, ",
  "৩।পরিধেয় জামা কাপড় Savlon/Detol দিয়ে ধুয়ে ফেলবেন, ",
  "৪। পরিবারের সবার চিকিৎসা করতে হবে।, ",
  "৫।কবিরাজী ও হমিওপাথি করবেন না, ",
  "৬।ডাক্তার এর পরামর্শ বাতিত অষুধ বন্দ করবেন না।"
  ];

let expectedArr = [];
let driverString = '';
var count = 0;
var length_= 0;
for(var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++){
   length_  = inputArr[i]+ driverString;
   if(length_.length <= 300 ){
    driverString = driverString + inputArr[i]; 
   }else{
    driverString = '';
    driverString = driverString + inputArr[i]; 
    count++;
    length_= 0;
   }
  expectedArr[count] = driverString;
}
console.log(expectedArr,expectedArr.length)
```

Comment: No, This is not the expected result. I do not want to count only the characters.
The element of the array has broken in the middle of the line!

It should not be. If the concatenation of the next element cross 300 characters, then it stops at the last one.

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora Updated but your expected output doesn't match with the condition `<=300`. let me know is that you want or not?

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora See my edit now :) it should work now

Comment: Sorry, your array returns 13 elements which are the same as the input array. But according to my requirements, the size of the output array will be 2. Anyways, I've solved it, you can check my answer below.

Comment: had some typo. check now